# React: Redux state and relations

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, redux, single-page-application

I'm developing admin GUI type react application. I'm using Redux to store the application state, mainly the API call status and domain objects. The domain model has dozen of entity types and the amount of data is very small.

I wanted to avoid nesting and keep the state normalized to avoid cyclic references. I designed the REST API to return data in normalized form. Currently the state structure is as follows:

```
{
  Foo: {
     byId {
       1: { id: 1, ... },
       2: { id: 2, ... },
       ...
     },
     isLoading: false
     isError: false
  },

  Bar: {
     byId {
       1: { id: 1, fooId: 1, ... },
       2: { id: 2, fooId: 2, ... },
       ...
     },
     isLoading: false
     isError: false
  },
  ...
}
```

Basically the state reflects the database. Now it's responsibility of a UI component to perform the "joins" on this data. Here is an pseudo-example:

```
// Redux connect omitted
FooListingComponent extends Component {

  // Redux-thunk actions
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getFoos() 
    this.props.getBars()
  }

  // Props comes from redux
  // Loading and error handling omitted
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.foos.map(f =>
          <Foo bars={this.props.bars.filter(b => b.fooId === f.id)} />) 
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is this solution fine in general, or should I reconsider the join logic and maybe shape the state at more fine-grained level either at Redux store or component level?

Comment: Keep your logic in Redux store. As it it written on a React Redux page you should use mapStateToProps to reshape the data from the store. Here is the link https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#let-mapstatetoprops-reshape-the-data-from-the-store

Comment: @Dominik Targosz Could you show me example? Note that in my sample the the FooListingComponent lists multiple Foos. Should I retrieve related bars inside the Foo component itself during mount? Or do you mean I should group bars by foos in the redux store?

Comment: You might want to consider using the selector pattern https://gist.github.com/abhiaiyer91/aaf6e325cf7fc5fd5ebc70192a1fa170, which allows you to refactor how you store state without changing mappings all over the place. It also lets you cache calculated fields, such as with https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect